# Combinations and permutations

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Find how many numbers there are between 100 and 999 in which all three digits are different.

How do I approach this type of question?

Comment: The answer of your question is here http://www.beatthegmat.com/counting-how-many-integers-from-100-to-999-t28441.html

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@F.Alanazi already directed to an elegant analytical way of answering your question.

Here I suggest an alternative empirical method for:

- any set of figures
- any repetition of digits

I wrote a simple function in R language:

```
unique.digits <- function(vec) {
  numbs <- as.character(vec)
  split.numbs <- strsplit(numbs, "")
  count.unique <- sapply(split.numbs, function(x){length(unique(x))})

  table(count.unique)
}
```

It finds the amount of figures composed by a single digit, two digits, three digits etc.

It can be tested with these examples:

```
> unique.digits(c(123, 101, 111, 222))
count.unique
1 2 3 
2 1 1 

> unique.digits(100:999)
count.unique
  1   2   3 
  9 243 648
```

In the case of your answer, we are interested in the amount of figures with 3 different digits, thus, 648.

Comment: It would be of interest to compare the performance of your program against that of a mathematical analysis for, say, 100 digit numbers.

Comment: @whuber you are totally right.  

I thought of generalizing the solution in one direction, when there is no pattern in the set of numbers, like my first example `c(123, 101, 111, 222)`, where, I think, mathematical analysis will fail.  

But my modest function is incapable of handling long numbers (ie. 100 digits) or large sets of numbers (it is already time demanding for a set of 1 million numbers and for larger sets R encounters memory issues).  

This indeed reinforces the idea that F.Alanazi provided the right answer, which involves combinatory, not my limited empirical suggestion.